# How to add an id to an existing div on click in css/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to html/css/js and I'm working on a small project where I have a few divs with the same classnames, for example:

```
<div class="imgBox">
    Something here...
</div>
```

None of them have an unique id. What I want to do is to add an id to a single div after I click on it. It would allow me to modify the selected div and make it in css fullscreen or something like that.

Do you have any ideas how to create a function in js for it?
I couldn't find a proper solution on the internet, but if I missed something, let me know.

Comment: Why has somebody voted to close this as "Needs More Focus"?  That is clearly NOT a correct close reason (there is only one question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure of your logic for wanting to add the IDs after the element is created, but this would add the ID attribute when you click the div.

```
var global_id = 1;

// click on div
$('.imgBox').on('click', function(e){
    
    existingID = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if (typeof existingID == 'undefined'){
        $(this).attr('id', global_id);
        global_id++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I realized that my logic had flaws, so I'll reorganize my idea, but your script may be helpful :) Thanks again

Comment: I just thought of this, but you'd probably want to prefix the id number with something, like myImgBox_1